# Does the movement of There and Back Again consume your movement for the turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, unearthed-arcana

The [mystic](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf) from Unearthed Arcana can get an ability called there and back again that states

> There and Back Again (2 psi): As a bonus action, you teleport up to 20 feet to an unoccupied space you can see and then move up to half your speed. At the end of your turn, you can teleport back to the spot you occupied before teleporting, unless it is now occupied or on a different plane of existence.

Now this states it is a bonus action to teleport **AND** move half your movement speed. If I am correct in understanding this that means you can (with standard 30ft movement) teleport 20ft, move 15, move action for 30 more, then action dash for 30 for a total of 95ft distance in a single turn. Then of course pop back like nothing happened.

Is this a correct assessment or does the ability also burn your movement action?

Comment: What book is this from? Is this Dreamscarred Press?

Comment: There are no move actions in 5e. do you mean spend your movement? Also, are you using the unearthed arcana mystic?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## The ability gives you extra movement.

First, note that there is no "movement action" in D&D 5e. On your turn, you can move up to your speed and take an action; these are separate things.

Second, note that the [Mystic](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf)  [isn't official](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/mystic-class), so the rules language in some of the abilities isn't as tight as you would find in published material.

The phrasing here is unusual, but following the general principle that abilities do what they say, I would assume that a Mystic using There and Back Again on their turn could do the following, in any order:

- Move up to their Speed, divided as they choose.
- Take one action
- Teleport up to 20 feet and then move half their speed.

And at the end of their turn they may return to the space they teleported from. If they took the Dash action and moved as described in the question, they could indeed reach a point 95' away before they teleported back at the end of their turn (or remained in position, at their option).

Comment: I thought UA material WAS official, just still in 5e's equivalent of "beta testing". I know its not legal in organized play yet. But it is still from Wizards of the coast correct?

Comment: @Erudaki It's developed by WoTC, but it is not yet official released content. It's playtest that may not be fully balanced (and definitely carries the caveat of not balanced for multiclassing.)

Comment: Just nitpicking: "And at the end of their turn they return ..." doesn't exactly match "At the end of your turn, you can teleport back ...", as the latter implies there is a choice involved.

Comment: Just nitpicking: from what you can see all over this stack, the rules' language in the published materials isn't all that tight either :-)

Comment: @hoffmale Thanks for pointing that out! I made the necessary edits.

Comment: @J.E Well, sure. I'm just saying that what makes it into the books is tight**er**.

Answer (score 4):

### There are no move actions in 5e

In 5e, your movement is available throughout your turn as a consumable resource to be spent before, between, and after actions.

### You effectively get new movement with this feature.

You are correct in figuring that you gain half your speed as additional movement after using this feature as a bonus action. If the ability consumed your movement it would say so. However, this 15 feet of movement must be taken *before* doing anything else (other than particularly timed reactions) since it is part of the bonus action.

Answer (score 4):

### Your assessment appears correct

Here's why I think so :

1. There is, as far as I know, no rule that implies movement abilities replace your normal movement.
2. The wording does not mentions the movement pool at all.
3. This seems to work using the same way the Battlemaster's Maneuvering Strike work. Which allows you to move half your speed as part of the Fighter's attack action (or reaction in the case of an attack of opportunity).
4. There is no move action in 5e. Movement is a seperate ressource pool that very rarely interacts with other actions.

### Example of an ability that restricts movement

The mystic's own class actually gives an example of an ability that acts differently. The nomad's Step of a Dozen pace is an example of a feature that is meant to interact with the player's movement pool.

> Step of a Dozen Paces (1–7 psi): If you haven't moved yet on your turn, you take a bonus action to teleport up to 20 feet per psi point spent to an unoccupied space you can see, and your speed is reduced to 0 until the end of the turn

As you can see, the ability mentions explicitely that you must not have moved yet and that you can't move afterward.